# What is the HTTP URL to stream the sub-stream channel from Dahua/CP-PLus camera

Tags: streaming, rtsp, ip-camera, http-streaming

I got the RTSP equivalent, which is:

```
rtsp://my_cam_ip:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1
```

I came across some equivalents in https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=CP+PLUS, like

```
http://my_cam_ip/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?camera=[CHANNEL]
```

but, it streams only from the main stream.

Comment: Why do you expect there to be such an URL? In general RTSP is favored over HTTP for live streaming and HTTP URLs are used merely as a fallback or snapshot mechanism. Either consult the manual or if the model supports ONVIF try to probe all the video locations via ONVIF.

Comment: I want to have the video shown up in a web-browser for my new admin system. Looks like streaming via HTTP can be easily wrapped inside a <video> tag, while rtsp wont. Chrome wont support any new rtsp play plugins, either.

Comment: The most reliable way is to remux the rtsp stream into an mp4 or webm stream either using ffmpeg or with your own code.

Comment: Well, I need to show the stuff up in a web page, and where do you think this remuxing  should happen ?

Comment: Why not on the same server that hosts the page?

Answer (score 3):

This works fine with dahua dh-ipc-hfw5421e-z

```
http://my_cam_ip/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?subtype=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been battling with this for an hour and based on experience with some other makes I've discovered that for the current (2017) Dahua models,  THIS WORKS if you want stream 2 in MJPEG stream:

rtsp://user:pass@:554/cam/realmonitor/channel=1&subtype=2

Subtype=2  not 1,  as indicated by documentation ( subtype=0 gives main and subtype=1 second H264 stream;  Dahua's firmware coder must have considered MJPEG to be a 'tertiary' choice ).

You of course need also to visit the stream configuration pages to put the second stream into MJPEG mode first.

Subtype=2 seems to be undocumented at the moment, I've just had to tell my Dahua dealer to add it to his notes.

Note that the stream wrapper is still RTSP,  it is just the compression payload which is MJPEG.  VLC will display it fine with the URL above.

Note that if you want an mjpeg stream in server-push format (ready for browser) you need to re-wrap it using CVLC or FFMPEG so it's available on a TCP listening socket.

~~~

[  Rudolfs Bundulis - with all respect you missed the point - most decent modern IP cameras can sustain two independent encoding processes so you can run an MJPEG output stream alongside one or more H264 main streams, so it is far more efficient to let the camera do it than to tie up additional hardware in transcoding the stream.  ]

Comment: Footnote:   NB  I find Dahuas to be very "picky" about receive client compared to Hikvision.   You may find the Dahua will display fine on the GUI-ed version of VLC,   but  not on CVLC or FFPLAY, for example.   [ Mind you I am in a complex tunnelled configuration here so that may have a part to play in this.  ]

Answer (score 0):

this one work perfectly for sub-stream

```
http://my_cam_ip/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?subtype=1
```

but i required main stream http url for DAHUA DH-IPC-HFW1120SP

```
http:///my_cam_ip/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?date=1&clock=1&resolution=[WIDTH]x[HEIGHT]
http:///my_cam_ip/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?camera=[CHANNEL]
```

the following url is not working